# Receive Images from another app to our app

Tags: android, image, firebase, share

So when I am in other media apps like google photos I select an image and click the share button then in the share window I want my app to be displayed so that i can click it and get that image to my app.
I have build a simple chat application where users can send text and images to each other where all the data is stored in Firebase.
So when one clicks my app in the sharing screen the image should take me to the Chat activity where i have all my chats so that i click one of my chats and the image is then sent to them.
So how to achieve this process?I have searched everywhere and couldn't get the hang of the right tutorial all i am finding is sharing data from our app and not from other app to our app.
Thank you.

Edit : I have created a separate activity that should be launched when a user choses to share a image from other app.But when i click my app in the sharing menu then my app goes all white screen instead of launching the SharingActivity.
Below is my code and manifest file.

SharingActivity.java

```
package com.pappu5.navigation;


public class SharingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendsData, SharingActivity.ShareHolder> frv;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private DatabaseReference dr, drUsers;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private String user;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);


        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.friendsView);
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends_Formed").child(user);
        drUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Chat_Profiles");
        dr.keepSynced(true);
        drUsers.keepSynced(true);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));

        Query personsQuery = dr.orderByKey();

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendsData> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendsData>().setLifecycleOwner(this)
                        .setQuery(personsQuery, FriendsData.class)
                        .build();

        frv = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendsData, SharingActivity.ShareHolder>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final SharingActivity.ShareHolder holder, int position, @NonNull FriendsData model) {
                holder.setDate(model.getDate());
                holder.setImage(model.getThumb_image());

                final String listUsers = getRef(position).getKey();

                if (!listUsers.equals(null))

                    drUsers.child(listUsers).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                            final String username = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String thumb = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();
                            //String online  = dataSnapshot.child("onlineStatus").getValue().toString();

                            if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("onlineStatus")) {
                                String userOnline = dataSnapshot.child("onlineStatus").getValue().toString();
                                holder.setOnlineStatus(userOnline);
                            }

                            holder.setName(username);
                            holder.setImage(thumb);
                            //holder.setOnlineStatus(online);

                            holder.view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    CharSequence[] actions = new CharSequence[]{"Share to " + username};
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                                    builder.setTitle("Select an Action");
                                    builder.setItems(actions, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                            if (i == 0) {

                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ChatActivity.class);
                                                intent.putExtra("id", listUsers);
                                                intent.putExtra("user_name", username);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder.show();
                                }
                            });


                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public SharingActivity.ShareHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.friends_status, parent, false);

                return new SharingActivity.ShareHolder(view);
            }
        };
        rv.setAdapter(frv);


    }


    public static class ShareHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;

        public ShareHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view = itemView;
        }

        public void setDate(String date) {
            TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.status2);
            username.setText(date);
        }

        public void setImage(String image) {
            CircleImageView thumb = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView2);
            Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar).into(thumb);

        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            TextView username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name2);
            username.setText(name);
        }

        public void setOnlineStatus(String onlineStatus) {
            ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.onlineStatus);

            if (onlineStatus.equals("true")) {
                image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }


    }


}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".SharingActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: it would be nice if you could provide more context to your question. some code you have tried. The structure of your code, the manifest file, etc. As a lead I would suggest to use an intent and define proper permission. This require to edit you manifest file and handle the Intent you your app activity. Intent are used to enable to switch from one activity to another whether the activity is part of your app or if the activity belong to another app.

Comment: Yes bro i know the concept of Intent but i am new to this sharing thing so as Shane mentioned i managed to make my app appear in the sharing menu now all i have to do is take that data and go to a specific activity in my app ,click the chat friend and the image should be sent.

Comment: @pascalsautot Bro i have edited my question please check it out

Comment: Bro,  I think Shane gave you the direct anwser hence there is no need to add anything since you confirmed it fixed/answered your problem/question. Thanks for completing the question, this might be usefull for other users. BR

Comment: no bro my app has just displayed in the sharing menu and my question is to receive images when i click the app and my question clearly states that so my question hasn't solved yet.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add below code inside Manifest.xml under activity tag like

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        // below code with show your app as sharing option
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

You can change mimeType according to your need.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Cool now i can see my app under the sharing menu so how do i go to a specific activity after i click my app in the sharing menu?

Comment: Shane i have updated my question please check it out once.